# Can a gulp plugin take in one file and return many files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, r.js

I am attempting to wrap the [RequireJS Optimizer](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) in a gulp plugin. There [have](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-requirejs) [been](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-rjs) [other](https://www.npmjs.org/package/amd-optimizer) [attempts](https://www.npmjs.org/package/gulp-amd-optimizer) to provide this functionality in gulp but none of them meet my needs.

A common approach to plugin development is to take files in, process them, and then hand them out; however that approach is not really compatible with how the RequireJS Optimizer works.

While it does not meet the gulp plugin [guidelines](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/guidelines.md), I am working on a different approach of taking in the [optimizer build configuration](https://github.com/jrburke/r.js/blob/master/build/example.build.js), processing it, and handing out the resulting file(s).

```
// Read in the r.js configuration
gulp.src( './build.js' )
    // Optimize the files according to the config
    .pipe( optimize() )
    // Return the resulting files for additional processing
    .pipe( size() );
```

Can a gulp plugin take in one file and return many files? If so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `vinyl-fs` to pass along the output of the optimization process.

```
var requirejs   = require( 'requirejs' ),
    through     = require( 'through2' ),
    vfs         = require( 'vinyl-fs' );

return through.obj( function( file, encoding, done ){

// Parse config from file

requirejs.optimize( config,

    // Success callback
    function( buildResponse ){
        vfs.src( config.dir + '/**/*.js' )
            .on( 'data', this.push.bind( this ) )
            .on( 'error', this.emit.bind( this, 'error' ) )
            .on( 'end', done );
    }.bind( this ),

    // Error callback
    function( buildError ){
        // Handle error
    } );
```

Usages ends up looking like...

```
// Read in build configuration
gulp.src( 'build.js' )
    // Run files from the config through the optimizer
    .pipe( optimize( settings ) )
    // Measure the size of the optimized files
    .pipe( size() );
```

Comment: I'm struggling with the same issue. Do you happen to have more concrete example of this? Like how is this then piped to fe. gulp.dest() handler? Also, what does the "callback" refer to?

Comment: I added some more detail. Given what the plugin does I don't need to use `gulp.dest()` but I don't see a reason why you couldn't.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes, simply emit multiple files.  The output simply needs to be one or more [Vinyl](https://github.com/wearefractal/vinyl) files.
2. Plugins only receive what is piped (emitted) to them.  That's sort of the whole point of using asynchronous pipes.

Take a look at [the plugin docs](https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/README.md) to understand how they work.